# Simperium - Can a user recover a forgotten password ..?

Tags: passwords, simperium

Hi I have implemented Simperium in my iOS app and will go live shortly, I have overriden the standard login-screens with my own using the authenticationOptional feature, all works well.

However, what happens if a user of the app creates a simperium account to use the sync features but then forgets their password....? My app uses simperium to not only sync the data to the simperium service for data security but also to sync between iPad and iPhone devices.

So, for example, the user set's up simperium login and then never touches it again for many months, they loose or change their iPad then want to retrieve the data but can't recall the password ... is their a way for them to retrieve it? by it being emailed for example ..?

Sorry if this is a silly question but I can't see an answer anywhere ...

Answer (score 3):

You can provide this functionality using the `reset_password` call from the auth api: https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/

That call though requires an API key with admin privileges (admin key in dashboard),
https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#reset_password

For security you'll want to keep that key on a server - and add a confirmation step (like email as you mentioned).

We're thinking about adding this as to the service so you don't need to implement this yourself though.