# Simperium username update doesn't require accurate password

Tags: php, curl, simperium

I'm setting up custom account management for my Simperium app, based on the recommendation from the answer in [Simperium - Can a user recover a forgotten password ..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604916/simperium-can-a-user-recover-a-forgotten-password), and referencing the [API documentation](https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#update).

This all in PHP, handling the form creation and submission.

I've created the curl request as follows, a format which I've already tested for password resets, using the "[reset_password](https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#reset_password)" url.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-Simperium-API-Key: <my_admin_API_key>'),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"username": "'.$username.'", "password" :"'.$password.'", "new_username":"'.$newusername.'"}',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://auth.simperium.com/1/<my_app_id>/update/'
));
```

The problem I'm having, is that during testing, I've found that it will take any password I enter, and return:

```
{"status": "success"}
```

Further testing showed that the username was, in fact, changed.

I realize this isn't a "question", per se, but Simperium support seems to be most responsive to Stackoverflow posts.

Comment: Make sure `$username` and `$newusername` are same

Comment: @manoj.admlab, why would I do that?

`$username` is the current username, and `$newusername` is what I want to change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the an API key with admin privileges, password is not needed. For inclusion in client apps, use a non-admin privileged API key - then password will be checked. The admin functionality is intended for use on your own servers where you are sure the key will not be leaked.